# SQL OR Linq: How to categorize into different batches when category changes

Tags: sql, linq, group-by

I have the following data:

```
Timestamp           Min     MAX     Category
2019-03-22 08:10    12.00   5.10    AAAA
2019-03-22 08:11    10.00   5.20    AAAA
2019-03-22 08:12    11.00   4.90    AAAA
2019-03-22 08:13    12.00   5.30    BBBB
2019-03-22 08:14    14.00   5.20    BBBB
2019-03-22 08:15    9.40    5.20    CCCC
2019-03-22 08:16    7.40    5.10    CCCC
2019-03-22 08:17    14.00   5.10    AAAA
2019-03-22 08:17    14.00   5.10    AAAA
```

I am looking for a SQL (or Linq) query to group this data based on the `Category` changes to be able to see the start and end of each category over time.

Comment: Would you please show us your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you are dealing with a *gaps and island* problem.

In pure SQL, this is usually solved using window functions and aggregation. The difference between row numbers gives you the group each record belongs to:

```
SELECT 
    category, 
    MIN(timestamp) start_timestap, 
    MAX(timestamp) end_timestap
FROM (
  SELECT
      t.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp) rn1,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Timestamp) rn2
  FROM mytable t
) x
GROUP BY category, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY start_timestap
```

In **[this DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2miv2d8RF2i7oz86a2vb7L/0)** with your sample data, this returns:

```
| category | start_timestap      | end_timestap        |
| -------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| AAAA     | 2019-03-22 08:10:00 | 2019-03-22 08:12:00 |
| BBBB     | 2019-03-22 08:13:00 | 2019-03-22 08:14:00 |
| CCCC     | 2019-03-22 08:15:00 | 2019-03-22 08:16:00 |
| AAAA     | 2019-03-22 08:17:00 | 2019-03-22 08:17:00 |
```

NB: this is a MySQL 8.0 DB Fiddle, however this is standard ANSI SQL that should work on any platform that supports window functions.

Comment: Awesome! That was exactly what I was looking for! Any idea on how to achieve the same result by LinQ lamda?